# Списки по условию pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas

Условие:

```
ko = ['длинна', 'A', 'B', 'C']
```

где: 'длинна', 'A', 'B', 'C' - столбцы в формате .xls (документ vhod.xls).

С помощью модуля `pandas` был загружен документ и созданы отдельные объекты `AAA, BBB, CCC` со списком значений больше нуля, однако если например в столбце `А` все значения равны нулю, то `ААА`-список будет ПУСТОЙ и дальнейшие операции над ним невозможны. Хотелось бы узнать, может возможно как то не создавать списки `ААА` либо `ВВВ` либо `ССС`, если все значения столба равны нулю и не включать в `Y`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее весь код идет в цикл с последовательным использованием `ААА, ВВВ` и `ССС`.

```
import pandas as pd
file = 'vhod.xls'
xl = pd.ExcelFile(file)
df1 = xl.parse('2')

AAA = df1[df1.A > 0]['длинна']
BBB = df1[df1.A > 0]['длинна']
CCC = df1[df1.A > 0]['длинна']

Y = [AAA, BBB, CCC]
for n in (0, len(Y)):
.............
.............
```

Comment: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: Приведите пример входных данных в таком виде, чтобы его можно было скопировать. Использовать данные с картинки затруднительно...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Исходный DF:

```
In [138]: df
Out[138]:
   длина  A  B  C
0    100  0  0  0
1    110  0  4  4
2    120  0  0  2
3    130  0  8  1
4    140  0  2  0
5    150  0  0  0
6    160  0  3  6
7    170  0  8  2
```

решение:

```
In [139]: Y = df.set_index('длина').apply(lambda x: x[x>0].index.tolist())

In [140]: Y = Y[Y.str.len() > 0].tolist()
```

результат:

```
In [141]: Y
Out[141]: [[110, 130, 140, 160, 170], [110, 120, 130, 160, 170]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
file = 'vhod.xls'
xl = pd.ExcelFile(file)
df1 = xl.parse('2')
Y = []
if len(df1[df1.A > 0]) > 0:
    AAA = list(df1[df1.A > 0]['длинна'])
    Y.append(AAA)
if len(df1[df1.B > 0]) > 0:
    BBB = list(df1[df1.B > 0]['длинна'])
    Y.append(BBB)
if len(df1[df1.C > 0]) > 0:
    CCC = list(df1[df1.C > 0]['длинна'])
    Y.append(CCC)
```

Comment: "страшненькое" решение... А если будет 10.000 столбцов? Зачем вводить ненужные переменные `AAA`, `BBB`, `CCC`?

Comment: костыль, как смог.